# How to select spinning values from listview?

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-spinner

I'm facing some issue with getting spinning values from list view.. in list view i have textview and related to spinner to it..

this is my Result.java

```
public class Result extends ListActivity{
SpinnerWrapper wrapper=new SpinnerWrapper();
Spinner sp;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.result);
    MyAdapter adap=new MyAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,R.id.textView1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.modules));
    adap.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    setListAdapter(adap);
    Button b=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button12);
    //final Spinner sp=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(Result.this,Cal.class);
            for(int i=0;i<15;i++){
                //String text= sp1.getSelectedItem().toString();
                //Log.d("This", text);
            }
            //Spinner sp1=og.getSp();
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(Result.this, R.array.grades, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            sp.setAdapter(adapter);
            sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(wrapper);
            intent.putExtra("values", sp.getSelectedItem().toString());
            //intent.putExtra("values", sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(wrapper));
            startActivity(intent);              
        }
    });
}
public void getObject(Spinner sp){
    this.sp=sp;
}

private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId,
            String[] strings) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, strings);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent,false);
        String[] items=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.modules);
        TextView tv=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);        
        tv.setText(items[position]);
        Spinner sp=(Spinner)row.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(Result.this, R.array.grades, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        sp.setAdapter(adapter);
        getObject(sp);
        //og.setSp(sp);
        //sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(wrapper);
        //int dd=row.getId();
        return row;     
    }
}
```

}

My Spinner Wrapper class is looks like this..

```
public class SpinnerWrapper implements OnItemSelectedListener {

public SpinnerWrapper() {

}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
     String text=parent.getSelectedItem().toString();
     int intee=parent.getSelectedItemPosition();
     String pos=Integer.toString(intee);
     String tex=parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
     Log.d("Selected", text);
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

I want to get spinning value of each spinner ..how can i do that??

Comment: What is the problem? Any exception  has

Comment: no..it's working fine.. when i tried to get value from spinner using String text=parent.getSelectedItem().toString() it only show 1 st value but not a selected value.. i have 14 spinners on the list and i want to get each selected values for each spinner seperately..

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you can't get the value by

```
 String tex=parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
 Log.d("You have selected", tex);
```

You can create an `ArrayList<String>` and add the selected value to that `ArrayList`. It will be something like this.

```
static ArrayList<String> sth = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
            long id) {
        Toast.makeText(
                parent.getContext(),
                "OnItemSelectedListener : "
                        + parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        for (int i = 0; i < parent.getItemIdAtPosition(pos); i++) {
            sth.add(parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString());
        }

        Log.w(getClass().getSimpleName(), "sth size " + sth.size());

    }
```

You can pass that `ArrayList` around since the selected values are stored.

Comment: value is coming but how i get all selected spinner values in list viee

Comment: you mean, all the previous selected values ?

Comment: yes.all selected values from spinners.actually i want to take them to another activity after invoking button click.

Comment: i will getting sth size as 0 and when i selected from upper spinner and scrolled down to last spinners the selected option in upper spinner automatically has changed to 1st option.this things happens to all spinners after scrolling..

Answer (score 0):

//sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(wrapper);

```
I see your code is commented. so the OnItemSelectedListener  is not called.

You call different listener for different spinner.
```

Comment: if i uncomment that statement it will update all the selected values while scrolling ..when loads the activity it will automatically updated with the first option in the spinner for all spinners in the list view..